# Is it true that $\frac{\mathbb{C}\{z\}}{(z-\alpha)^n}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ denote the ring of convergent power series in $z$ around $\alpha$. Consider the ideal $(z-\alpha)^n$ in $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$. Is it true that $\frac{\mathbb{C}\{z\}}{(z-\alpha)^n}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $n$, with basis $1, (z-\alpha),\dots , (z-\alpha)^{n-1}$?

What goes into proving this fact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Convergent"... **where** ? At least at $\;\alpha\;$ , in some neighborhood of $\;\alpha\;$ ....? Are those convergent power series *about* $\;\alpha\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio : oops, sorry for the mistake. They are convergent at $\alpha$.

Comment: Your basis is missing $(z-\alpha)^0=1$. You need to prove two things: A) $(z-\alpha)^i, i=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ are linearly independent modulo the ideal. B) they span the quotient ring. In other words, given a power series $f(z)\in\Bbb{C}\{z\}$ there exists constants $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ such that
$$f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(z-z_0)^i+ g(z)(z-\alpha)^n$$ where $g(z)\in\Bbb{C}\{z\}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : So, does that mean the statement is at least true? I know the analogous statement to e true in polynomial rings, but not sure how to prove it for the power series case, since I don't know of any analogue of division algorithm in polynomial rings. I've added the basis 1.

Comment: Yes, it is true. You just fill in the details missing from DonAntonio's sketch, and you are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\;V:=\Bbb C\{z\}/\langle (z-\alpha)^n\rangle\;$ is definitely a ring and, thus, an abelian group. It's not hard to check it is also a $\;\Bbb C\,-$ module, which already turns it into a complex vector space.

Now, if for some $\;c_1,...,c_{n-1}\in\Bbb C\;$ we have that

$$c_1(z-\alpha)+\langle (z-\alpha)^n\rangle+c_2(z-\alpha)^2+\langle (z-\alpha)^n\rangle+\ldots+c_{n-1}(z-\alpha)^{n-1}+\langle (z-\alpha)^n\rangle=\overline 0$$

then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k(z-\alpha)^k\in\langle (z-\alpha)^n\rangle\iff\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k(z-\alpha)^k=f(z)(z-\alpha)^n\;,\;\;f(z)\in\Bbb C\{z\}$$

which is absurd as the left side has a zero of order *at most* $\,n-1\,$ at $\;z=\alpha\;$ , whereas the right hand has a zero at the same point of order **at least** $\;n\;$ (why?) .

Thus, the vectors $\;(z-\alpha),...,(z-\alpha)^{n-1}\;$ are $\;\Bbb C\,-$ linearly independent in $\;V\;$.

Finally, any element in $\;V\;$ is an expression of the form $\;f(z)+\langle(z-\alpha)^n\rangle\;$ .But we can write

$$f(z)=(z-\alpha)^kg(z)\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;g(z)\in V\;\;\text{that doesn't vanish at}\;\;\alpha$$  and thus...well, try to take it from to show that group of vectors is a generator of $\;V\;$...but you seem to be missing the vector $\;1\;$ .

Comment: I realize that you may just be giving a sketch, but... in a proof 1) the OP is to conclude that the displayed identity implies $c_0=c_1=\cdots=c_{n-1}$ (not that there is a contradiction), and 2) nothing bad will happen, if on the third line from the bottom $g(z)$ vanishes at $\alpha$. It **will** vanish at $\alpha$ for **some** choices of $f(z)$. Instead, you need to be concerned about whether $g(z)$ converges in some neighborhood of $\alpha$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, but after the OP corrected his definition of $\;\Bbb C\{z\}\;$ I think it is clear these elements converge in some neighborhoodo fo $\;\alpha\;$ , as opposed to converge only at $\;\alpha\;$ as that'd make the question pretty boring. I think the OP can fulfill these details.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for the answer. Just to sum it up, according to your hint, we can assume without loss of generality that $k\leq n-1$  in the expression of $f$ ; then we'll replace $g(z)$ by $g(z)-g(\alpha)+g(\alpha)$, so that the first term vanishes  at $\alpha$, then apply the same trick to write $g(z)-g(\alpha) = (z-\alpha)^l.h(z)$ with $h(z)$ nonvanishing, and continue with $h(z)$. We see that $l\leq k$, so the process will stop. Hope I got it right.

Comment: @yojusmath Yes, assuming $\;k<n\;$ makes no harm as any higher power it "swallowed" by the idea. The rest seems to be a good idea indeed.